# Is there a way to customize the indicator shape and padding of the NavigationRailIndicator in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for an alternative way to customize the indicator shape of Flutter's navigation rail indicator. I've done things like wrapping it around with a container and changing the shape, but it stays with the default StadiumBorder class.

I want to make the indicators to look like rounded-square shaped instead of rectangular where it takes a lot of extra padding space (which is what RoundedRectangleBorder class does).

Any workarounds? It's a pretty good-looking widget.

```
NavigationRailDestination(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  icon: Icon(Icons.speed),
  label: Text(
    'Dashboard',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 13,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    ),
  ),
),
```

I tried customizing the indicatorShape property in NavigationRail, but stays the same with StadiumBorder.

Comment: _"tried customizing the indicatorShape property in NavigationRail"_ -- what have you tried? it works for me. For example:
```indicatorShape: const CircleBorder(),```

Comment: I've tried CircleBorder and RoundedRectangleBorder, but I want it to have a perfectly Square Shape. But, thank you for the heads up, I will revise my question. The only problem is that I can't remove the default padding from the options of indicatorShape.